# Haar measure- $T-$ invariant

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups

Let $\mathscr{G}=(G,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$ be a measure-preserving dynamical system, and let $G$ be a locally compact topological group.

Let $(G,*)=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, and let $T:G\rightarrow G$, $T(r)=2r=r+r$$($mod $1)$.

Let $m$ be the Haar measure on $G$.

Is $m$ $T-$invariant?

I tried to show it myself, but ran into a problem because the Haar measure is invariant under
multiplication, which means $+$.

And moreover, if the answer is yes, then Haar is unique?

Comment: The Haar measure is the Lebesgue measure of $\Bbb{R}$ then $d T(r) = 2 dr$

Comment: @reuns What do you mean by $d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $m$ is $T$-invariant even though Lebesgue's measure on $\mathbb R$ is not invariant under the transformation $x\mapsto 2x$.  The reason is that, by definition,  $m$ is $T$-invariant iff
$$
  m(T^{-1}(E)) = m(E),
  $$
for every measurable set $E$,
and it so happens that, at least for all small enough arcs $A\subseteq G$, one has that  $T^{-1}(A)$ consist of **two**  arcs, each of which has half the length of $A$, and hence, together, they have the right measure.

Regarding uniqueness, it is a well known result that Haar measure is always unique (regardless of invariance by whatever transformations) up to scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but on $[0,1]$ Haar measure is Lebesgue's measure up to scalar multiplication, right?

Comment: $[0,1]$ is not a group.  If you are asking whether  Haar measure on $G$ is the same as Lebesgue's measure, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, I ment for $G$, thank you!